# Python-lambda aws: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: How can i parse real path

Tags: python, xml, amazon-web-services, dom

and having some Problems. I am trying to parse thee path with dom.minidom.

Example:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import time
import logging
import rds_config
import pymysql
import os
import io
import zipfile
import gzip
import urllib
import tempfile
import botocore
import traceback
import datetime
import boto3
import uuid 
import xml.dom.minidom
from concurrent import futures
from io import BytesIO
from datetime import timedelta,datetime

def readingXML(self,ruta):
    try:
        print('readingXML...')
        #self.s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        #ruta = xmls/(xmlname.xml)
        full_path = "s3://"+self.bucket+"/"+ruta
        print(full_path)
        doc = minidom.parse(full_path)
        #variables de xml - Comprobante
```

And got this Error message:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u's3://mi-bucket/xmls/A91C7BE1-015A-4A1A-9A85-3B065122E1EB.xml'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifying an S3 url which minidom does not support. You need to download first and then process.

You will need to look up your S3 file's URL. The AWS S3 Console can provide that. Let's assume it is http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myfile as the variable urlpath. Also verify that the object has public access.

1) Download the file into memory

```
import requests
urlpath = 'http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myfile'
r = requests.get(urlpath)
```

2) Create the DOM object (parse XML):

```
import xml.dom.minidom
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(r.content)
```

Now you have your DOM object is loaded. Process as desired.

Note: my example code does not process or detect errors.

[EDIT]

If the S3 object is private, then you will need to add code using the AWS Python SDK (boto3) that uses AWS credentials to access the S3 file.

Comment: can not access by url. Exist any alternative like send the path by a boto3 object?

Comment: I updated my answer. Yes of course you can use the AWS SDK (boto3) to access and download the file. There are a ton of examples on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I will drop on the bucket folder a .zip with many folders and with xmls file, i have to look inside validating only the xml file and parse them with xml.dom to save some info.

Comment: Close this question out if my answer is correct and open a new question on how to process zip files stored on S3 in Python.